# Make + key act like Tab in a form using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a web application using AngularJS.

Within a form, the client wants the + key to work like the Tab key. The form contains static text inputs, a submit input, and buttons. It will also contain dynamically added text inputs, which are added using ng-repeat.

I thought I could do this by capturing the keypress event and changing the keycode, but that is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this using an angular directive. Place this directive on an element. Within that element, it will add a keypress listener to all inputs and buttons; it will even handle dynamically added elements!

```
app.directive('nspPlusAsTab', function() {
  function getNextTabbableElement(indexOfCurrentElement, tabbableElements) {
    var indexOfNextTabbableElement;
    var lastIndexInTabbableElements = tabbableElements.length - 1;

    if (indexOfCurrentElement === lastIndexInTabbableElements) {
      indexOfNextTabbableElement = 0;
    } else {
      indexOfNextTabbableElement = indexOfCurrentElement + 1;
    }

    var nextTabbableElement = tabbableElements[indexOfNextTabbableElement];

    if (nextTabbableElement.disabled) {
      nextTabbableElement = getNextTabbableElement(indexOfNextTabbableElement, tabbableElements);
    }

    return nextTabbableElement;
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      //use jQuery.on to attach a keypress event handler function to all current and future input or button elements
      element.on("keypress", "input, button", function(event) {
        var plusKeycode = 43;

        if (event.which === plusKeycode) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();

          var tabbableElements = element.find("input, button");
          var indexOfCurrentElement = tabbableElements.index(this);
          var nextTabbableElement = getNextTabbableElement(indexOfCurrentElement, tabbableElements);
          nextTabbableElement.focus();
        }
      });

    element.on("focus", "input", function(){
      this.select();
    });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to capture the key press event, suppress it (stop propagation, prevent default), and then send a new custom keypress event.

Comment: I have caught the event, stopped propagation, and prevented the default. But I can't figure out how to raise the custom keypress event using angularjs

Comment: I don't know how to link off the app but post  566481, www.stackoverlow.com/questions/596481 maybe, has a pure Javascript implementation. I would suggest wrapping this in an Angular module.